# GitHub markdown not rendering and git detecting changes when no changes

Tags: git, github, markdown

There's a glitch that I've noticed in GitHub markdown, the VSCode markdown extension and other places too. It's behaving particularly unusually on GitHub and using git.

Very frequently when I type in headings such as `# heading` or `## sub-heading`, the heading does not render correctly. Here is an example commit for a markdown file:

Source diff:

[image]

Rich diff:

[image]

As you can see, the rich diff isn't rendering correctly, and so isn't the file when I go into "browse files" (regardless of what computer/device I use):

[image]

Somehow, after deleting the space character after `###` and re-typing it, there were changes to be committed. From my knowledge this shouldn't happen (because nothing has actually changed, I just re-typed the space character). But I committed it anyways and got the following diff:

[image]

As you can see the space character is highlighted. Now I magically get the following rich diff, which is now showing the heading:

[image]

And now, when I "browse files", the heading shows on every computer I use:

[image]

This is happening to my a lot, and I'm wondering why this is happening, how git is even able to commit no change, and if there is a way to solve this?

This is definitely not just me because others have mentioned this to me too in the past.

Note: My GitHub repo is private so I can't share a link, but it should be easy to reproduce.

**Update**

I opened the revision with the issue inside HxD and got the following hex output:

[image]

I then replaced the space character inside VSCode and got the following hex output:

[image]

There's an extra `Â` character that is not shown in VSCode and that I didn't input. I've had this problem on both Windows and Mac OS.

**Update 2**

Both ascii and utf-8 define the character as `Â` so I can't figure out why it's not showing up in VSCode or GitHub text editor.

I've also seen ascii defining it as the following on https://www.asciitable.com/

[image]

Comment: _“how git is even able to commit no change”_ – Well, the thing is that there **is** a difference as you can see from the fact that there is a diff. It’s likely that the space between the `###` and the title isn’t a normal space which could also be the reason why the Markdown parser doesn’t pick it up as a heading. Can you copy/paste the exact string so we can check what actual character is used there? You can also open the file in a hex editor and look at the actual bytes that are in there to figure out what character there actually is.

Comment: \xa0 is "non breaking space" which is I guess not recognized by github's markdown as a valid space character in a header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The byte sequence `0xC2 0xA0` is the UTF-8 sequence of for the character [`U+00A0` NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). So it is a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character which explains why it is looking like a space in editors and shows up as a difference when compared to a simple space.

The fact that it shows up as `Â` within the hex editor is simply because hex editors only ever display ASCII in the text representation since they only look at a single byte at a time. So they don’t look for character sequences like this which is required for UTF-8 to encode characters outside of the ASCII space.

As for why the non-breaking space breaks the Markdown parser, this is expected if the parser conforms to the [CommonMark specification](https://commonmark.org/). According to it, the ATX headings are [required to be followed by a space](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#atx-headings), where a space is [explicitly defined](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#space) to be a `U+0020` SPACE character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still confused as to why VSCode and GitHub markdown editor randomly decide to insert a "non-breaking space" instead of a normal space from time to time.

Comment: @DavidCallanan I have just realised why this is happening to me at least - the keybind to insert a non-breaking space on Mac OS is just Option+space, which means that if you accidentally hold Option after doing Option+3 to create a markdown heading #, you insert a non-breaking space by mistake.

Answer (score -2):

Another cause may be an improperly named file or missing .md file extension.